# Can't filter or order by using relational-pouch plugin

Tags: database, angular, couchdb, pouchdb, relational-pouch

Since last two days I have been trying to sort and/or filter documents in pouchdb using a plugin relational-pouch but its not working for some reason

I have read the docs from Pouch DB's official documentation and followed the steps, i.e, I created an index and then called the `find('type',options)` method with document type and options as given in the code below, but the results I get is ordered by id's, the tricky part is I can pass the "limit" option in the options and it works but on the same place "sort" option doesen't seems to work, also it would be help full if someone can point me to a place where I can find how to filter in relational-pouch, the official GitHub docs won't help

```
get() {
this.db.createIndex({
  index: {
    fields: ['title']
  }
}).then((data)=>{
  this.db.rel.find('content', {
    limit : 1,
    sort: ['title']
  }).then((data)=>{console.log(data)});
}).catch(console.log)
}
// the schema applied
this.db.setSchema([
  {singular: 'user', plural: 'users', relations: { contents: {hasMany: 'content'}}},
  {singular: 'content', plural: 'contents', relations: { user: {belongsTo: 'user'}}}
]);
```

I am expecting results which are ordered by title(i even tried ordering  by created), but I am getting the following:

```
{title: "Test title 5", description: "Test description 5", created: "2018-12-20T02:44:59.127Z", modified: "2018-12-20T02:44:59.127Z", id: "2A57FB9C-4E29-590C-AA4E-751FAA0F0AD9", …}

{title: "Test title 2", description: "Test description 2", created: "2018-12-19T03:40:56.302Z", modified: "2018-12-19T03:40:56.302Z", id: "2F568411-D955-42ED-9622-1C191AD6532D", …}

{title: "Test title 4", description: "Test description 4", created: "2018-12-20T02:44:51.654Z", modified: "2018-12-20T02:44:51.654Z", id: "319D2427-5862-477A-AAEA-CB2536C2430E", …}

{title: "Test title 1", description: "Test description 1", created: "2018-12-19T03:40:50.166Z", modified: "2018-12-19T03:40:50.166Z", id: "4D982FA6-99A9-4545-BC10-CBEF9530B3FA", …}

{title: "Test title 6", description: "Test description 6", created: "2018-12-20T02:45:06.927Z", modified: "2018-12-20T02:45:06.927Z", id: "7C4637AB-B626-E5FD-9353-5A7F926B98ED", …}
```

Comment: I STRONGLY recommend you start with the very first example in GitHub (  `db.rel.save('author', { name: 'George R. R. Martin', id: 1, books: [6, 7]
}` etc., etc,   ), and examine the data structure that `relational-pouch` writes to your database.  Without a solid understanding of the structure you're going to go round and round in circles.  If that does not help then, please edit your question to include examples of your raw data and the schema you applied to your database (using this.db.setSchema([{def},{def}, ...]);).

Comment: @MartinBramwell after your recommendation i have edited the question and added the schema applied, also i have gone through documentation and tried following their step by step guide but, at the point where i need to sort with any other field other than id it just does not works, although i would like to get one thing in your notice that there is no mention of sort functionality in the docs of Relational-pouch

Comment: I am concerned that your output results do not resemble the typical output of a relational pouch find operation.  This would happen if you are trying use relational pouch to retrieve data that was not previously written by relational pouch.  As I said before, relational pouch has a particular storage structure that you must respect if you want to use it.  I really recommend that, with an empty database, you experiment with all the various documented examples before trying to work on your own data.

Comment: @MartinBramwell first of all thank you for your fast responses, as i mentioned in the comments after your recommendation i have followed the official docs to create a sample database (in relational pouch npm) but even there when i come to a point of sorting i can't, i tried their "post" example

Comment: It maybe that relational-pouch does not support explicit sorting, only implicit as I note in my update to my answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way.  "... thank you for your fast responses."  The way to express thanks in S.O. is to click the little up arrow icons beside each of the valid answers and helpful comments. I just upvoted your question, because it's a valid issue.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to retrieve large numbers of records, there is only one good way to do it: `allDocs`.

`relational-pouch` is intended for work on a small collection of records related to one, or at most a small few, individual records.

The two tools are quite compatible and, with some experimentation and planning, work very well together. I work on large datasets with `allDocs`, render lists in the browser with `live-find` and, when the end-user picks a single item, retrieve it's related records for display/alteration with `db.rel.find()`.  In such a case sorting is not an issue at all.

In other words ... if you NEED sorting and filtering you probably ought to get a short list of primary (master) records first, and only then use their key properties in db.rel.find() to retrieve their secondary (supporting, related, detail) records.

To emphasize ... **`allDocs`** should be your main tool and your design decisions should focus on it, not on relational-pouch.

**Update:** 2018/12/23 16:00 est

If all you need to do is ensure your records are in date order, just ensure that your IDs are in date order...

```
{id: "Test_2_20181219034050166", title: "Test title 1", description: "Test description 1", created: "2018-12-19T03:40:50.166Z", modified: "2018-12-19T03:40:50.166Z", …}
```

Check out the reference to sorting in the comand [db.rel.find(type)](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/relational-pouch#dbrelfindtype).  You generate such specialized IDs with the class method [db.rel.makeDocID(parsedID)](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/relational-pouch#dbrelmakedocidparsedid).

Comment: actually all i care about is that my data should come sorted in descending order of created date, it would be very helpful if you can show some demo code on how to achieve that  and also i can assure you my data set is small,

Comment: You may have to use [Javascript Array.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) to get descending order.

Comment: i will surely apply your recommendations, meanwhile i was thinking: if somehow i could be able to use pouchdb's default find(after creating index for any field like title, date, etc) with a selector that only gives me "posts", and also it has a sort option which can help me sort (may be according to title, date). i currently do require sorting by date only but in case i require sorting on other fields.

Comment: Yes.  That'll work.  If you want your user's view of the data to update automatically when another user alters it, investigate `live-find`. It gives you the full magic of background replication.